# Does any CI service let you build Docker containers and use the docker build cache?

Tags: continuous-integration, docker, circleci

I have a bunch of Docker containers all hooked up using docker-compose (previously fig). I have found that services that advertise themselves as "Docker CI" services are usually just talking about using Docker to run their build workers.

I would like a continuous integration service that preserves the Docker build cache between runs, instead of spinning up a completely new worker/filesystem/build context. Otherwise, builds take absolutely forever. Ideally managed (unlike https://github.com/groupon/DotCi, which doesn't come with CircleCI's ready-to-go per-build database).

The only thing I've found is TeamCity (old, you can't version build tasks in a yaml file easily like you can with CircleCI, you have to maintain infrastructure, etc). Quay.io doesn't provision a database like CircleCI and Travis do, so you have to bifurcate dev and prod and install one inside the container and run unit tests during the container build (ew - you can't spawn into an unbuilt container to debug things!).

How do you run continuous integration on your Docker container cluster?

Comment: Note that it is now possible to build docker images on Travis as well,  https://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-08-19-using-docker-on-travis-ci/

Answer (score 15):

### CircleCI 1.0

CircleCI lets you build Docker containers as part of your build: https://circleci.com/integrations/docker

You are however right that this doesn't cache the Docker images - it's a bit tricky on our stack to do that right, but we are planning on addressing that soon.

In the meantime, a number of customers have cached it using CircleCI's built-in (non-Docker) caching, by using `docker save`/`docker load`: https://circleci.com/docs/docker#caching-docker-layers. It's not ideal, but it should tide you over until we're able to support this a lot better.

### Updated for CircleCI 2.0

CircleCI 2.0 is Docker-centric. You can build Docker images, utilize layer caching, use Docker Compose, and even use official and custom Docker images as your build environment.

Comment: I wish `docker load` did that, but it doesn't preserve the build cache. `docker load` takes about as much time as pulling a fully build image from a private repository so it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Paul would you have an update about the "planning on addressing that soon" part? It would be interesting.

Comment: Based on my testing, it's my understanding that even the `docker save/load` strategy as linked does not work (the docker build commands are fully run at each build), as per this comment here: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-1-10-0-is-available-beta/2100/15 @paul-biggar, or anyone- is there a working example?

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using CircleCI, see http://tschottdorf.github.io/cockroach-docker-circleci-continuous-integration for a good guide to use the docker cache

shippable is also worth checking out, as their entire infrastructure is based around docker and orchestrating multiple docker containers with [shippable formations](http://docs.shippable.com/formations_overview/).

Comment: just a quick fix, looks like the URL for the blog post works only without the trailing slash as it will return 404: http://tschottdorf.github.io/cockroach-docker-circleci-continuous-integration

Answer (score 2):

> Codeship now supports storing the Docker image cache and retreiving this in order to speed up your builds.

https://codeship.com/documentation/docker/caching/

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question ["How can I let the gitlab-ci-runner DinD image cache intermediate images?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35556649/291573).

Even if [our solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36268709/291573) requires a minimal amount of infrastructure maintenace (we need to run our own runner), I think it is worth a look.

Basically we do not run Docker in Docker, but we are creating a separate VM for runners only. This has some implications about security and cleanup tasks, please see also the [README](https://github.com/schmunk42/docker-gitlab-runner) of our runner.

Maybe this solution will become obsolete in the future as Docker support for various CI systems gets improved, but right now it's a good mixture between performance, maintenace and usability.

Answer (score -2):

Have you seen [wercker](http://wercker.com/)? It supports "bring your own container", will cache your images (I think on a per-worker basis, but after a few builds usually the startup reduces to a few seconds with a custom image), and afaik also allows building Docker images.

Downside: it requires [far too many GitHub permissions](https://github.com/wercker/support/issues/20).

Comment: It doesn't even let you use your own `Dockerfile` so it is not a good solution.

Comment: @SteffenBrem: You can build your images from your Dockerfiles at docker hub and use them in wercker. Works for me.